Overloading ref-qualified member-function without ref-qualifier
Is the non ref-qualified overload of member-function f in accordance with the C++20 standard? Both Clang and GCC seem to accept it. Are they both pulling on the short end of the stick? What does the C++20 standard has to say about it?
#include <concepts>

struct s {
    int f(auto...)&;
    void f(auto...); // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
};
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(s{}.f()), void>);

Demo

MSVC's error message:
<source>(5): error C2559: 'void s::f(_T0...)': cannot overload a member function
without ref-qualifier with a member function with ref-qualifier


Do you specifically mean C++20 as published?  There are retroactive bug fixes to consider otherwise.

@DavisHerring The question is specifically directed towards the C++20 standard as published. But by all means, feel free to mention what has or will be changed in newer C++ versions, as this would also be highly appreciated.

In c++20's first post-publication draft N4868, this is ill-formed as explained here.

tldr; This is DRP1787. The program is ill-formed in c++20 as published. Later a DR was made through P1787 that removed the entire subclause [over.load] making the program well-formed.

First note that you've what is called abbreviated function template. Meaning the member function f in your examples are actually templated.
Now, coming to the issue.

What does the C++20 standard has to say about it?

This is ill-formed in c++20 as published. Note that later DRP1787  removed this restriction so that the program is actually well-formed as a result of this DR. So, as publisshed in c++20 draft, from over.load:

Member function declarations with the same name, the same parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]), and the same trailing requires-clause (if any), as well as member function template declarations with the same name, the same parameter-type-list, the same trailing requires-clause (if any), and the same template-head, cannot be overloaded if any of them, but not all, have a ref-qualifier ([dcl.fct]).


Note that you code is equivalent to:
#include <concepts>

struct s {
    template<typename... T>
    int f(T...)&;
    template<typename... T>
    void f(T...); 
};
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(s{}.f()), void>); //only msvc rejects while both clang and gcc accepts 

Post C++20
The entire clause [over.load] was removed as a DR in P1787:

[over.load]
Remove subclause, referring the stable name to [basic.scope.scope]. Update the surviving cross reference (in [class.mem]/5) to refer to [basic.scope.scope].
Parts of the notes and examples are adapted in [basic.scope.scope]/3 and [dcl.fct]/5.


This ruling seems to apply to C++20 standard as published, but I can no longer find it in later drafts. What happened to this passage? Was there at some point a defect report accepted that later changed this?

@303 Yes, [over.load] was removed and replaced/changed/updated etc post-c++20. I'll add another answer(or perhaps update this maybe) for c++23. But since the question asks specifically for c++20, I think this answers your question.

It depends if that change is expected to be applied to C++20 standard retroactively, as it so happens with many accepted defect reports.

@303 Yes, but I don't think this should be a DR? If it was done as a DR then yes, that will be applied retroactively to c++20.

Yes, the relevant change is a DR.

@DavisHerring sorry, which change in that URL removes the above over.load text?  I cannot find it.  (A many 100 if not 1000 line change, even if it does modify the above text, makes a really poor reference to anything at all.)

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont: It removes the whole subclause!  (There’s a reason I made a comment on the question suggesting it might be good to ask about C++20 as amended…)

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont Just below over.pre, there it is mentioned that over.load is to be removed. Updated the answer.

Removing the subclause didn’t necessarily mean it became well-formed—the rules were moved to [basic.scope.scope].  However, the usual rule is that function templates can be distinguished even if only by their return types, so that regularization did make this particular case valid.

@303 To me this answer answers both the question about the rules in C++20 as published and what's happened to C++20 since then via a DR - but does it answer your question "What does the C++20 standard has to say about it?" as you see it? If not, what more would you want from an answer? What is missing?
